# 'Request had insufficient authentication scopes' from Google Translate API in R

Tags: r, google-translate

I am currently working on analyzing twitter data , however when I attempt to translate twitter text data through the translate() package leveraging the use of Google API in R I get this error.

```
 t <- gl_translate(my_data$text, source="ar", target="en", )
2020-07-19 11:25:30 -- Translating text: 69597 characters - 
ℹ 

2020-07-19 11:25:32 > Request Status Code:  400

2020-07-19 11:25:32 -- API returned: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 204800 bytes.
2020-07-19 11:25:32 -- Attempting to split into several API calls
2020-07-19 11:25:32 -- Translating text: 98 characters - 
Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
ℹ 2020-07-19 11:25:33 > Request Status Code:  403
Error: API returned: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

why does it produce this error?

this is my code:

```
gar_auth(email="**@**.com")
set.key('****')
t <- gl_translate(my_data$text, source="ar", target="en", )
View(t)
```

Comment: Please read [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how do I ask a good question, [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to create a MCVE as well as [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R. Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., abstract from your real problem...

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`googleLanguageR`](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=googleLanguageR) package (it is not clear from the question itself), it seems like an authentication issue.

You'll probably need to authenticate with:

```
library(googleLanguageR)
gl_auth("translate_api_key.json")
```

To get the JSON authentication file, see [Google Cloud Translation - Creating service accounts and keys](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup#creating_service_accounts_and_keys).

For details on authenticating the `googleLanguageR` package in R, see [Language tools for R via Google Machine Learning APIs - Authentication](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleLanguageR/#authentication).

Note that Google API has some [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing#prices_per_month) for this.

If you want to use a Google Translate API key rather than JSON file, there are:

- [`translate`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=translate) package, where you store you API key in `getOption("google.key")` variable, or you pass a `key` argument with you API key, and
- [`github/sumtxt/datatools`](https://rdrr.io/github/sumtxt/datatools/man/gl_translate.html) package with `gl_translate()` function, where you can provide the API key in the `key` argument as well,

but note that you have to generate you API key in Google Cloud Console as well (not to be confused with a password of your Google account).

Comment: Thank you Petr for your answer, I am using the transate() package once I performed what you suggested it translates the first line in my text, is there any possible way to make it translate all text data I have?

Comment: @FatemahAlnofal Then it's probably not vectorized, i.e. you need to provide only one string at a time. You can use `dplyr` package for this or you can try to vectorize that function with `my_translate <- Vectorize(gl_translate)` and then use  `t <- my_translate(my_data$text, source="ar", target="en")`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @PetrKazjar I have vectorized the data yet returns only one row of translation

Comment: @FatemahAlnofal OK, then please let me know exactly your package... package [translate](https://cran.r-project.org/package=translate) doesn't seem to have function `gl_translate()`, so you maybe use something else?

Comment: yes, I changed to the translate package due to authentication issues.                    this is my code getOption("google.key")
gar_auth(email="fatima@ekadkom.com")

set.key('**')

my_translate <- Vectorize(translate)

t <- my_translate(my_data$text, source="ar", target="en", ) }

Comment: @FatemahAlnofal Yes, thanks! Then try to run `t <- sapply(my_data$text, translate, source = "ar", target = "en")`.

Comment: Still only translate the first line of my data.

Comment: @FatemahAlnofal That's strange. So resolve this question (which is basically about authentication) and open a new question with this new problem, please, there will be certainly someone who could help with this.